# ORACLE pass through query for SAS

Tags: regex, oracle, sas

I'm writing a pass through query in sas.
How do I make this search case insensitive to search a narative text?
Thank you in advance.

```
PROC SQL INOBS =1000;     CONNECT TO ORACLE as con1
    (DBMAX_TEXT=... PATH=...="dba" pw="mypassword");

   CREATE TABLE PHRASES AS 
   SELECT *
      FROM CONNECTION TO con1 (
      SELECT 

"T1"."DOC_ID", 
"T1"."NRTV_TXT"  ,
REGEXP_INSTR(NRTV_TXT,'LOOKING FOR TERMS|USED FORMS')"POSITION",
REGEXP_SUBSTR(NRTV_TXT,'LOOKING FOR TERMS|USED FORMS' ) "PATTERN"
FROM   "NRTV" "T1"


    );

   DISCONNECT FROM con1;
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UPPER()` to convert the value to upper case before looking for the patterns:

```
REGEXP_INSTR(UPPER(NRTV_TXT), 'LOOKING FOR TERMS|USED FORMS') "POSITION",
REGEXP_SUBSTR(UPPER(NRTV_TXT0, 'LOOKING FOR TERMS|USED FORMS' ) "PATTERN"
```